# Dart json_serializable Cannot populate the required constructor argument. It is assigned to an ignored field

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a flutter app and i need to serialise a class to json. The class is :

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
@JsonSerializable()
class CartItem extends HiveObject {

  @HiveField(1)
  String item_id;

  @HiveField(2)
  String name;

  @HiveField(3)
  SelectionsList selections;

  @HiveField(4)
  String special_instructions;

  @HiveField(5)
  int quantity;

  @HiveField(6)
  double amount;

  @HiveField(7)
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  MenuItem item;

  CartItem(this.item_id, this.name, this.selections, this.quantity, this.special_instructions, this.amount, this.item);
}
```

however, due to the `item` field being ignored (intended), when i try to generate the .g.dart file, this error is thrown. `Cannot populate the required constructor argument: item. It is assigned to an ignored field.` I still need it to be in the constructor though, So is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this working. Not sure if it is the correct way but if it helps you out then great.

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
@JsonSerializable()
class CartItem extends HiveObject {

  ...

  @HiveField(7)
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  MenuItem item;

  CartItem(this.item_id, 
this.name, this.selections, this.quantity, this.special_instructions, this.amount, 
[this.item = MenuItem.empty()]);
}
```

You have to set the constructor entry an optional positional and give it a default value.
You can also make it nullable and leave out the default on the constructor item.

Comment: Hey @Pieter van der Vyver, thank you for answering this question, Could you confirm, that you were able to generate the hive and json-methodes for this class. Because in my [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74290802/build-runner-failing-for-classes-extending-hiveobject) the build_runner fails to generate the methodes for the json-serializable. Would be a big help if you could confirm it worked for you in the past.

Comment: Hi @Donatic. To be honest I cannot remember. Last December I had some free time between projects and I had this issue in a random project I was helping a friend out on. Best I can suggest is to give it a try. I am sure I tested this before posting it.